# Make Jabber.el stop alerting me when new messages are written on MUC, unless I'm highlighted

Tags: jabber

I tried to follow [emacswiki article about Jabber.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/JabberEl) to configure it on my Emacs. However, my changes do not works.

- Alerts stealth the minibuffer, and its annoying to see an alert when I'm doing something there.
- I get alerts for every message people send to MUCs, which is something I would really like to avoid and instead being alerted when somebody highlights me.
- I cannot set xmessage for alerts (I tried linnotify, but it doesn't works; maybe is something with my tiled window manager SpectrWM), and when some activity happens the MUC's name is added to the modeline, clobbering it.

Jabber.el is a great package, but this things make it annoying and distracting, how can I fix them?

My Emacs conf for Jabber.el:

```
(setf
 jabber-history-enabled t
 jabber-use-global-history nil
 jabber-backlog-number 40
 jabber-backlog-days 30
 jabber-alert-presence-message-function (lambda (who oldstatus newstatus statusnext) nil)
 jabber-invalid-certificate-servers '("chat.deshackra.com")
)

(defun notify-jabber-notify (from buf text proposed-alert)
  "Notifica sobre nuevos mensajes en Jabber vía notify.el"
  (when (or jabber-message-alert-same-buffer
           (not (memq (selected-window) (get-buffer-window-list buf))))
    (if (jabber-muc-sender-p from)
        (notify (format "(MP) %s"
                        (jabber-jid-displayname (jabber-jid-user from)))
                (format "%s: %s" (jabber-jid-resource from) text)))
    (notify (format "%s" (jabber-jid-displayname from))
            text)))

(defun my-jabber-chat-delete-or-bury ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq 'jabber-chat-mode major-mode)
      (condition-case e 
          (delete-frame)
        (error 
         (if (string= "Attempt to delete the sole visible or iconified frame" 
                      (cadr e))
             (bury-buffer))))))

;;(define-key jabber-chat-mode-map [escape] 'my-jabber-chat-delete-or-bury)
;;(add-hook 'jabber-alert-message-hooks 'notify-jabber-notify)

(if (daemonp)
    ;; nos conecta a todas las cuentas jabber!
    (progn 
      (load-file (expand-file-name "jabber.secret.gpg" user-emacs-directory))
      (ignore-errors 
        (jabber-connect-all))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you customize the variable `jabber-alert-muc-hooks` (`M-x customize-option RET jabber-alert-muc-hooks`), you'll see that most of the alerts come in pairs, one with `-personal` appended, i.e. `jabber-muc-echo` and `jabber-muc-echo-personal`.  Disable `jabber-muc-echo` and enable `jabber-muc-echo-personal`, and you'll only see alerts when someone highlights you.

"Highlighting" is defined as a message starting with your nick, followed by one of the symbols in `jabber-muc-looks-personalising-symbols`.

Comment: By some weird reason, I keep getting alerts in my mode-line. Any suggestion on how to debug this?

[this is what I have related to jabber.el in my custom.el file](http://dpaste.com/245A3DG)

Comment: That's strange.  Perhaps you could try `M-x debug-on-entry` on `jabber-muc-echo`, and see where it gets called from.

Comment: The problem wasn't with `jabber-muc-echo` but with `jabber-activity-mode`, I just turn it off (`nil`) from `Easy Customization` and it fixes my issue!